# Single Data Point for Each Record

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to join four tables together (APPLICANT, WIA_REG, CASE_NOTES, WIA_TRANSACTIONS) and get a single result for each participant. However, I am currently getting all the records for each participant from the tables being joined and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The criteria here is I want the max date from two of the tables.

```
select  
    APPLICANT.ID as ID,
    APPLICANT.USERNAME as USERNAME,
    WIA_REG.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME,
    WIA_REG.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME,
    WIA_REG.BIRTH_DATE as BIRTH_DATE,
    WIA_REG.PROGRAM_CODE as PROGRAM_CODE,
    WIA_REG.REGION_CODE as REGION_CODE,
    WIA_REG.REG_DATE as REG_DATE,
    WIA_REG.STATUS_CD as STATUS_CD,
    WIA_REG.STATUS_DATE as STATUS_DATE,
    CASE_NOTES.SERVICE_DATE AS LAST_CASE_NOTE_SERVICE_DATE,
    CASE_NOTES.SUBJECT AS CASE_NOTE_SUBJECT,
    CASE_NOTES.NOTES AS CASE_NOTE,
    WIA_TRANSACTION.SERVICE_CODE AS SERVICE_CODE,
    WIA_TRANSACTION.SERVICE_DATE AS SERVICE_DATE
 from 
    WIA_REG WIA_REG,
    APPLICANT APPLICANT,
    CASE_NOTES CASE_NOTES,
    WIA_TRANSACTION WIA_TRANSACTION
 where 
    APPLICANT.ID=WIA_REG.APPLICANT_ID
    and APPLICANT.ID=CASE_NOTES.APPLICANT_ID
    and APPLICANT.ID=WIA_TRANSACTION.APPLICANT_ID
    and WIA_REG.STATUS_CD ='AC'
    and WIA_REG.PROGRAM_CODE IN('ADULT','DW')
    and WIA_REG.STATUS_DATE between '01-JAN-2018' and '31-DEC-2019'
 order by username asc, service_date desc, last_case_note_service_date desc;
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to use traditional 'join' syntax as I am working in an oracle system.

Essentially, I am looking to get the only the latest record from each of the table and have it as one row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - Based on @Littlefoot's suggestion, this is my query:

```
SELECT a.id,
       w.last_name,
       w.first_name,
       c.subject,
       c.notes,
       c.service_date,
       t.service_date
  FROM wia_reg w
       JOIN applicant a ON a.id = w.applicant_id
       JOIN case_notes c ON c.applicant_id = a.id
       JOIN wia_transaction t ON t.applicant_id = a.id
 WHERE     w.status_cd = 'AC'
       AND w.program_code IN ('ADULT', 'DW')
       AND w.status_date BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'
       AND c.service_date = (SELECT MAX (c1.service_date)
                           FROM case_notes c1
                          WHERE c1.applicant_id = c.applicant_id)
       AND t.service_date = (select max (t1.service_date)
                            from wia_transaction t1
                            where t1.applicant_id = t.applicant_id)
 order by username asc;
```

And this is an example of the results:

| ID | Subject | Note | Service Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | xyz | Nov |
| b | 2 | jkl | DEC |
| b | 2 | jkl | DEC |
| b | 2 | jkl | DEC |
| c | 3 | bnm | MAR |
| c | 3 | bnm | MAR |
| c | 3 | bnm | MAR |

When really I just want one record for each ID. Any idea how to get those unique IDs?

Comment: I would try and use that entire sql statement to get only the IDs. Then use a separate select statement to get the max date record where the ids are in the original sql statement.

Comment: BTW, Oracle has supported ANSI join syntax since about v9i. I assume your Oracle system is not older than that?

Comment: @user1854438, would that be in the form of a subquery? Any chance you could showcase what something like that would look like in a very general outline?

Answer (score 1):

> The criteria here is I want the max date from two of the tables.

There's no such a condition in your `WHERE` clause.

---

> I am not sure what I am doing wrong

See above

---

This is how I understood it (along with some other objections):

- as commented, use `JOIN`s (unless you're really on *ancient* Oracle database version)
- use table **aliases**; yes, you used them, but - your aliases are equal to table **names** which doesn't make any sense
- don't compare dates to strings. If `status_date` column's datatype is `date`, `'01-JAN-2018'` is surely a string. Don't rely on Oracle's capabilities of implicit datatype conversion. The fact that it *works* for you at the moment doesn't mean that it would work elsewhere (your code would certainly fail on my database). Use e.g. `date literal` (as I did), or `to_date` function with appropriate format mask which - preferably - doesn't use any language-specific elements (e.g. don't use `JAN` with `MON` format mask, but `01` with `MM`)

As of code itself: see lines below the comment `--`; it fetches the MAX date from `wia_reg` table, while relation is `applicant_id` column. I *presume* that's how it should be done. If there's some other column that should be used to join them, use it.

You'd do the same for another table you mentioned (I'm not sure which one is it).

```
SELECT a.id
       -- and all other columns
  FROM wia_reg w
       JOIN applicant a ON a.id = w.applicant_id
       JOIN case_notes c ON c.applicant_id = a.id
       JOIN wia_transaction t ON t.applicant_id = a.id
 WHERE     w.status_cd = 'AC'
       AND w.program_code IN ('ADULT', 'DW')
       AND w.status_date BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'
       --
       AND w.reg_date = (SELECT MAX (w1.reg_date)
                           FROM wia_reg w1
                          WHERE w1.applicant_id = w.applicant_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough comment. When I utilize your code, it does not return a single observation for each ID - there are multiple rows for the same ID. Instead of w.reg_date I utilized c.service_date and did an additional max statement for t.service_date as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I was just guessing *which* date column you're talking about. As I don't know your data model, no wonder I failed, but - you should know which column(s) to use, now that you know how.

Comment: Would you take a look at my edit? Still not able to get a single value for each ID.

Comment: Looks like all you need is `select DISTINCT`.